How to smooth the demarcation between two materials?
I want to have a different material on this part of the mesh.
Since assigning a material to it creates a sharp and jagged demarcation between materials, I thought to use a vertex group, and smooth it in the shader nodes. With geometry nodes, I captured a vertex group, outputting the attribute for use the in shader nodes. I was going to use this as the factor for a mix shader node, blending between the two materials (one as a node group). My problem is that I can’t find any way to smooth the jagged edges.


How do I smooth the edges? Or is there a better way to have a different material on a part of the mesh? I don’t want a texture based solution, nor a destructive one (I need it to be easily editable).

Did you try the smooth brush in Weight Paint mode?

Robin, Gorgious, you were wrong you pervs :)

You can use the "Smooth" operator in weight paint mode.

